# creating subreport with iReport tool for JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm working on a `struts` based application. I want to create a Jasper report containing questions and responses for a *`Paper`* Object. Clearly I have a List of *`Paper`* objects containing part attribute and each *`Paper`* object internally has a List of *`Questions`*. Also each *`Question`* has a List of Responses.

I could create the main report with Paper object which displays different part names. But I want to display the questions associated with the part and responses associated with each question.

My Model classes will be:

```java
// Paper
public class Paper {

    public String partName;
    public List<Question> questions;
}

// Question
public class Question {

    public String question;
    public List<Answer> answers;
}

// Answer
public class Answer {

    public String answer;
}
```

I know I have to use subreport in `iReport`. When i did so the compilation fails for the data source expression `new JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{questions})`

Comment: Responses should go here to help people with similar problems in the future.  You say that compilation fails, could you give any error message associated with the failure?  You have given your class structures but not any report information.  Where are you using that expression?

Answer (score 1):

new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{questions})

Answer (score 0):

PerFect............ In addition Please import classes in your main report

```
 <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"/>
 <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"/>
```

and subreport tag would have

```
<subreport isUsingCache="true">
<reportElement x="0" y="39" width="555" height="276"/>
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{addresses})]]></dataSourceExpression>
<subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "report1_subreport5.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

And subreport would just look like normal fields. note: subreport will not comiple and would give error that it is not able find the field in the bean.