# Designing JRXML for java beans as datasource having nested java beans in them

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

I am currently working on a project where I need to use Jasper Reports. I want to generate a Jasper report using JavaBeans as `datasource` to the JRXML or more precisely Jasper file. So, the input to the Jasper file will be a list/collection of beans. My Java Bean is as follows:

```
myBean1 {
    field1;
    field2;
    ...

    //Constructors and getter-setters as per normal bean convention.
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that, amongst these fields, one of them is a list of another bean say `myBean2`. `myBean2` has two fields and respective getter- and setter methods.

So, the structure of `myBean1` is as follows:

```
myBean1 {
    field1;
    field2;
    List<myBean2> list;

    ...

    //Constructors and getter-setters as per normal bean convention.
}
```

So every object of `myBean1` will have variable number of elements in the list of `myBean2`.
The structure of the report that I want to generate is as follows:
(Consider `List<myBean1>` is given as datasource to the Jasper file.)

So, report will look like:

```
myBean1_Object1:
    field1
    field2
    myBean2Object1.field1
    myBean2Object1.field2
    myBean2Object2.field1
    myBean2Object2.field2
    ......
    ......
    myBean1_Object2 :
        field1
        field2
        myBean2Object1.field1
        myBean2Object1.field2
        myBean2Object2.field1
        myBean2Object2.field2
```

Due to the list of `myBean2` in `myBean1` I am facing difficulty in designing the JRXML.
Please provide me some hint for implementing the JRXML.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083406/creating-subreport-with-ireport-tool-for-jasperreports

Comment: To solve the issue, I have used sub-reports. The idea is pretty simple, add the normal fields as they are in the design file, and for the list elements create another jrxml design file with the elements of the bean (the bean you will pass as list). Add this other jrxml file as subreport in the original file and set the datasource as that subreport as list and pass the list of beans as the datasource. It will solve your issue. Incase of any queries, post a comment.